# Hint: $\sin^2(6x)-\sin^2(4x) = \sin(2x)\sin(10x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need a hint to solve prove $\sin^2(6x)-\sin^2(4x) = \sin(2x)\sin(10x)$

I tried several solutions, including taking $(\sin(6x)+\sin(4x))(\sin(6x)-\sin(4x))$ but every time I ended up with a ridiculously large equation, I'm sure there is a more elegant way to solve this.

Note: I'm looking to go from the L.H.S to the R.H.S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [sum to product formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities),
$$
\sin6x+\sin4x=2\sin5x\cos x,
\qquad
\sin6x-\sin4x=2\sin x\cos5x,
$$
so the left-hand side becomes
$$
4\sin5x\cos x\sin x\cos5x
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: how to proceed further pleasee explain?

Comment: @Bhaskara-III Recognize $2\sin5x\cos5x=\sin10x$ and $2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, $$\sin^2(6x)-\sin^{2}(4x)=\sin(2x)\sin(10x)$$
$$(\sin(6x)-\sin(4x))(\sin(6x)+\sin(4x))=\sin(2x)\sin(10x)$$
$$(2\cos(5x)\cos(x))(2\sin(5x)\cos(x))=\sin(2x)\sin(10x)$$
$$2(2\sin(5x)\cos(5x))\cos^2(x)=\sin(2x)\sin(10x)$$
$$2\sin(10x)\cos^2(x)=\sin(2x)\sin(10x)$$
$$\sin(10x)(2\cos^2(x)-\sin(2x))=0$$
$$\sin(10x)(2\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x))=0$$
$$2\sin(10x)\cos(x)(\cos(x)-\sin(x))=0$$

Comment: What part of "I need a hint" led you to answer the entire question?

Comment: @Thomasandrews unfortunately we have no control on what others can write as answers. We can only comment. +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using $z=e^{i2x}$ and the definition of the sine and De Moivre's formula, rewrite the equation as

$$(z^3-z^{-3})^2-(z^2-z^{-2})^2=(z-z^{-1})(z^5-z^{-5}).$$ (The denominators $(2i)^2$ simplify.)

It is an easy matter to check that both members are

$$z^6-z^4-z^{-4}+z^{-6}.$$

Comment: Very nice approach. +1